# Shoppingcart counter without page reload

Tags: jquery, counter

I have simple webshop and in navigationbar I have shoppingcart glypicon where I want to display amount in cart before order is sent.

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/api/Carts',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    let counter = 0;
    $.each(data, function(index, val) {
      let uname = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userName'));
      if (val.CompanyID == uname && val.IsInCart == true) {
        counter = counter + 1;
      }
    });
    $('#cartsum').append(counter);
  }
})
```

I would like this to work inside `$(".glyphicon-shopping-cart").on("click", function(){});` when product is added to cart, then counter counts rows in cart, but nothing I have tried is working. 
I tried to put that code inside function and call that function inside `$(".glyphicon-shopping-cart").on("click", function(){})`, but that didn't work. I'm beginner so maybe I just did something wrong. 
Thanks for any help with this!

Comment: Are you sure 100% sure that the element (`.glyphicon-shopping-cart`) is exists when the code is running (for example, it could be a dynamic content, generated by a script). Also, are your code is wrapped with `$(document).ready` or eq?

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using?

Comment: Code is inside $(document).ready and if I understood question, yes, (.glyphicon-shopping-cart) exists.

Comment: @AlonEitan I have 3.4.1 jquery version

Comment: @HeiJoe So the `success` callback was [removed](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-special-case-deferred-methods-removed-from-jquery-ajax) in that version, try `$.ajax({ ... }).then(function(data) { <place the success code here > });`

Comment: @AlonEitan It's working just like my original code. Question was how to get that function work without refreshing page?

Comment: Oh, so perhaps I didn't understand - If the click event is attached to a `<a>` element then pass the event object to the function like this: `$(".glyphicon-shopping-cart").on("click", function(e){ e.preventDefault(); < rest of the code > });` and if this doesn't work then we'll need to see the relevant HTML and how you bind the click events

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204736/discussion-between-heijoe-and-alon-eitan).

Comment: Sorry, I have to go soon, but I strongly suggest that you [edit] the question and include more details (Like the relevant HTML and also how you call the ajax function) - I'm sure someone will help you, and if not then I'll take a look when I get back :)

Comment: @AlonEitan I got it working, thank you!